# how to run multiple text files as input in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I wrote a python code which will take input of a txt file and print to excel . I'm able to achieve for one txt file giving as input . But the requirement I have will have around a million of txt files in a folder . SO I don't know how to change the python code to take the input from a folder .

The below code handles input 1.txt file . I want to run multiple txt files from a folder , That's my requirement .

```
with open('C:/test/1.txt') as infile:
    registrations = []
    fields = OrderedDict()
    d = {}
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            key, value = [s.strip() for s in line.split(':', 1)]
            d[key] = value
            fields[key] = None
        else:
            if d:
                registrations.append(d)
                print(d)
                d = {}
                if ',' not in line:
                    print('line without ,:', line)
                    continue
    else:
        if d:    # handle EOF
            registrations.append(d)

with open('C:/registrations.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(registrations)
```

Thanks,
Meera

Answer (score 0):

Use the pathlib module:

```
from pathlib import Path


FOLDER = Path('your/folder/here')

for file in FOLDER.glob('*.txt'):
    # Do your thing
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your source code, I optimized it. I use `os.walk` to access each .txt file and then read it line by line in those txt files and save it in an enum. Then I will check each line in that enum.

```
import os

extension = [".txt"]
path = "C:/test"
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()       
        if ext in extension:
            with open(file_path, "r") as f:
                try:
                    f_content = f.readlines()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            for l_idx, line in enumerate(f_content):
            # ..................................

# l_idx: return position line
# line: content in line
```